# Scroll To Top button that only appears when you reached the end of the page

Tags: scrolltop

I think this is rather easy achieved, but I couldn't find out how to- and couldn't find much documentary about it.

I hate those 'scroll to top' buttons that appear after you already scrolled just 300px. Like I'm that lazy to scroll to top on myself. Therefor I would like to have a scroll to top button that only appears when you reached the bottom of the page (minus 100vh (100% viewport height).

Let's take in account the button is called `.scrollTopButton` and it's CSS is `opacity: 0` and it's `position: fixed` on default.

How would I make the button appear when you reached the bottom of the page, minus 100vh and scroll along?

*I was thinking of comparing the body height minus 100vh with (window).scrollTop().*

```
var vH = $(window).height(),
    bodyMinus100vh = ($('body').height() - vH);
if (bodyMinus100VH < $(window).scrollTop) {
  $('.scrollTopButton').toggle();
};
```

Comment: so, what is the question?

Comment: Couldn't you just absolutely position in at the bottom of the body in css?

Comment: You could, but it should scroll along with you, as you reached 'almost the bottom of the page'. Therefor a fixed position isn't an option.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it myself. Quite easy, honestly.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var     vH = $(window).height(),
          bodyHeight = ($(document).height() - (vH * 2)),
        // When you open a page, you already see the website as big
        // as your own screen (viewport). Therefor you need to reduce 
        // the page by two times the viewport
    scrolledPX = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrolledPX > bodyHeight) {
        $('.scrollTopButton').css('opacity', '1');
    } else {
        $('.scrollTopButton').css('opacity', '0')
    };
});
```